# Show popup message with auto close and on top of all of the windows

Tags: powershell, popup

I need to create a function that shows a message to the user and if the user doesn't respond then it automatically closes the windows.

```
   function ShowMsg ($timeout,$message)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Company Name"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
$label.Text = $message
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,40)
$form.Controls.Add($label)

#add button to form
$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = $timeout * 1000
$timer.add_tick({$form.Close()})
$timer.Start()

$form.Topmost = $true
$form.ShowDialog()

$form.Dispose()
}

$timeout = 30

ShowMsg -message “This is the message you will see on the window`nMessage on new line” -timeout $timeout
$r = ShowMsg -message “This is the message you will see on the window`nMessage on new line” -timeout $timeout
if ($r -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    Write-Host “Press ok now”
}else{
    Write-Host "$r"
}
```

I try to use the above code but after showing the message 3 or 4 times it starts closing the popup and in the output, I see "cancel"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywAbe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the timer.

In the form declaration, where you create the timer object, initially set it to `$timer.Enabled = $false`.

Next, add a `$form.Add_Shown({$timer.Enabled = $true; $timer.Start()})` event handler to start the timer when the form is first shown.

In the Tick event of the timer, tell it to `Stop()` and close the form.
Don't forget to dispose of the timer aswell:

Try

```
function ShowMsg ([int]$timeout, [string]$message){
    Add-Type -AssemblyName system.windows.forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName system.drawing

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = "Company Name"
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
    $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $form.Topmost = $true

    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
    $label.Text = $message
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,40)
    $form.Controls.Add($label)

    #add button to form
    $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
    $okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $okButton.Text = 'OK'
    $okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.Controls.Add($okButton)
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton

    $timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    $timer.Enabled = $false           # disabled at first
    $timer.Interval = $timeout * 1000
    $timer.Add_Tick({ $timer.Stop(); $form.Close() })

    # start the timer as soon as the form is shown
    $form.Add_Shown({$timer.Enabled = $true; $timer.Start()})

    $form.ShowDialog()

    # clean-up
    $timer.Dispose()
    $form.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the "good old" wshell-popup like this?:

```
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
$timeout = 5
$objShell.Popup('Here comes the sample text', $timeout)
```